# Desenvolver loading em etapas com JS/PHP

Tags: php, javascript, carregamento

Tenho uma tela em PHP onde eu tenho algumas etapas para serem feitas, conforme essas etapas são feitas, o navegador fica em *branco e carregando*, então gostaria de colocar um loading, onde iria mostrar para o usuário o que está sendo feito.

As etapas que eu faço são:

```
1 - Consultar API.
2 - Calculando Resultados.
3 - Gerando Arquivo.
```

E cada etapa, é uma função que eu faço em PHP. Como posso encaixar um loading em execução para o usuário verificar que o processo está sendo executado?

Eu utilizo Framework Codeigniter para o PHP e Bootstrap.

Answer (score -2):

Uma prática para exibir o status do código que está sendo processado em reloads mais lentos ou com maior processamento, como processamento em lote, load de arquivos, envio de emails em massa, etc é voce usar a função flush do php, sugiro dar uma olhada na documentação, mas resumindo o que o flush faz é exibir na tela o que já foi processado até o ponto onde ele está e continua o processamento.
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.flush.php

Como você não colocou o código, vou colocar de uma forma genérica o processo e voce pode adaptar à sua realidade...

```
   for($x=0; $x <= 10000; $x++){
        echo 'bloco 1 - linha'. $x.'<br>';

  }

  flush();
//  Aqui ele explode na tela o primeiro bloco antes de começar a processar o segundo...

   for($y=0; $y <= 10000; $y++){
        echo 'bloco 2 - linha'. $y.'<br>';

  }

  flush();
//  Aqui ele explode na tela o segundo bloco antes de começar a processar o terceiro...
for($z=0; $z<= 10000; $z++){
        echo 'bloco 2 - linha'. $z.'<br>';

  }
  //ao completar o processamento ele vai exibir o restante da página
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas eu gostaria de fazer esse loading na parte front-end, onde o usuário iria ver que está sendo executado as etapas. Não acho que essa função poderia me ajudar.

Comment: o código processado é em php? se for tem que ser assim... vou editar e voce analisa se serve pra vc